# Random div selector

Tags: php, javascript, random, generator

```
<?php $page = $wp_query->post->ID;
switch ($page) {
case is_page (449) : 
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var rightdivs = $('.random-right').get().sort(function(){return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;}).slice(0,1);$(rightdivs).appendTo(rightdivs[0].parentNode).show();</script>";
break;
case is_page (7) : 
case is_page (197) : 
case is_page (214) : 
case is_page (218) : 
case is_page (11) : 
case is_page (260) : 
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var rightdivs = $('.random-r right').get().sort(function(){return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;}).slice(0,3);$(rightdivs).appendTo(rightdivs[0].parentNode).show();</script>";
break;
case is_page (212) : 
case is_page (216) : 
case is_page (452) : 
case is_page (226) : 
case is_page (228) : 
case is_page (230) : 
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var rightdivs = $('.random-right').get().sort(function(){return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;}).slice(0,4);$(rightdivs).appendTo(rightdivs[0].parentNode).show();</script>";
break;
case is_page (236) : 
case is_page (254) : 
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var rightdivs = $('.random-right').get().sort(function(){return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;}).slice(0,5);$(rightdivs).appendTo(rightdivs[0].parentNode).show();</script>";
break;
// Uncomment to add 6 CTA's onto long enough pages
/*case is_page () :
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var rightdivs = $('.random-right').get().sort(function(){return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;}).slice(0,6);$(rightdivs).appendTo(rightdivs[0].parentNode).show();</script>";
break;*/
case is_page (220) : 
case is_page (238) : 
case is_page (256) : 
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var rightdivs = $('.random-right').get().sort(function(){return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;}).slice(0,7);$(rightdivs).appendTo(rightdivs[0].parentNode).show();</script>";
break;
case is_page (15) :
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var rightdivs = $('.random-right').get().sort(function(){return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;}).slice(0,8);$(rightdivs).appendTo(rightdivs[0].parentNode).show();</script>";
break;
// Uncomment to add 8 or 9 CTA's onto long enough pages
/*case is_page () :
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var rightdivs = $('.random-right').get().sort(function(){return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;}).slice(0,9);$(rightdivs).appendTo(rightdivs[0].parentNode).show();</script>";
break;*/
default :
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var rightdivs = $('.random-right').get().sort(function(){return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;}).slice(0,2);$(rightdivs).appendTo(rightdivs[0].parentNode).show();</script>";
}
?>
```

I am coding some call to action boxes to be displayed randomly on the right hand side of my site, I have got it to work fine but I would like to take it a step futher and get it to not display the call to action div that is relevant to that page, i.e:

Click here to find out about us - not to be displayed on the about us page.

Above is what I have so far.  As you will be able to see the divs that hold the text and images for the call to actions are called 'random-right'.  They all have the same class of "random-right" and a corresponding id of "right-cta-1", "right-cta-2" etc; the links are formatted as so; "" as I am developing it in WP so didn't want to use absolute links just for flexibility.

Hope someone can help as it has been driving me mad :)

Comment: sorry just noticed a typo it should say the links are formatted like this; index.php?page_id=(whatever page id number)

Comment: I know I will need to reference the link to check against the page id:

Comment: <a id="5" href="index?page_id5">Link here</a>

Comment: and then check against the var $page, so <?php if $page == getElementbyID->whatever it is to get; then if they match pick a different one

Comment: Managed to get 95% of the way there I have got it to do what I want apart from to pick another div if one of the selected divs values is equal to the page id, I have just got it to hide it:

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>

var bodyID = $('#cta_dis').attr('value');
var rctaNum = $('.random-right').attr('id');


var rightdivs = $('.random-right').get().sort(function(){
          return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;}).slice(0,9);$(rightdivs).appendTo(rightdivs[0].parentNode).show();

var Value = $.each(rightdivs, function(){
            $(this).attr('value')
               });



for (var n = 0; n < rightdivs.length; n++) {
 alert ($(rightdivs[n]).attr('value'));
 if ($(rightdivs[n]).attr('value') == bodyID) { 
  $(rightdivs[n]).hide();
 } 
}

</script>";